# Why can't Android phones render this KML poly?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, android

Our outage map works well in browsers and most mobile devices. The map can be found here:
[Test Outage Map](http://www.hydroottawa.com/newsevents/map_test.cfm?LANG=E&template_id=555)

However, on Android phones the perimeter polygon is rendered as black. Have tried changing the polystyle but that does not work. The outage polygon is displayed properly if the boundry is commented out.

[Screenshot of Android render](http://www.hydroottawa.com/newsevents/android.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Google Android are you using?

Comment: I tested it at 8:50am EDT, June 9 using the default browser in Android 4.0.4. The polygon rendered correctly as a blue outline, the same way it appeared on my computer. This may be a problem with Android version (as Mapperz noted) or browser.